# Physical Memory growth with django-haystack, using the SOLR backend

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I have a django webapp with 2 models and roughly 250k rows of each model in a database. Wanted to implement a search yesterday, so installed haystack along with the SOLR backend. It worked great.

After setting up SOLR (the memory usage of SOLR without any indices is 100MBish) and adding 3K indices as a test, I could not help but notice that the RAM consumption of SOLR (start.jar) spiked up to 200MB. A 100MB jump for 3k models?

Is something wrong with my setup? I followed the default haystack-solr installation instructions, schema.xml and etc. The models themselves are not that big, if that matters.

Just to clarify, everything works fine, the memory is just a bit high though. Is it the case that the first few thousand indices cause a big RAM spike, but the next few hundred thousand don't? Because 100MB for 3k rows to the index way to high if I plan on indexing 500k in the future.

Sorry if my question is a bit vague, im a beginner at this, Thank you.